# Memcached client for Windows in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memcached

I need a portable C/C++ solution, so I'm looking for a C/C++ client library for Memcached that work on both Windows and Unix. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's libmemcached in C. Should be most portable :)

Answer (score 1):

http://people.freebsd.org/~seanc/libmemcache/

HTH